# can I access private variable in method in same class?

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

I have this controller

```
class PageController extends Controller
{      
    private $myid;    
    public funciton index(){
     }    
   public function viewbyid($id){
      $this->myid = $id;
     return view('someview');
   }

   public function getRecord(){
        $id = $this->myid;
         echo $id; //it would be null here,if I am going to access this method.
        return view('anotherview');
   } 
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's what `private` means.... [RTFM](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php)

Comment: but I tried it returns null

Comment: Then where are you setting it? Where are you calling `viewbyid()`?

Comment: I did not use setters, I only have that code

Comment: should I use setters for that ?

Comment: If you don't assign any value to $this->myid, then it will be null.... you even have a method that sets it, why don't you call that method?

Comment: $somevar = $this->myid = $id;

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92934/discussion-between-jemz-and-mark-baker).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can access private varible, in side class any where, Your using OOPS PHP. So may be problem is you might be accessing `getRecord()` method with diff object.

**For Eg:**

```
$obj=new PageController();
$obj->viewbyid("Test");
$obj->getRecord();//Then it will display the result
```

If your reinitialize an object or creating new object then that object will reallocate memory, so previous saved values will not be present.

**For Eg:**

```
$obj=new PageController();
$obj->viewbyid("Test");
$obj=new PageController();//$obj will allocate memory in diff location so your previous values will be initialized to default.
$obj->getRecord();//Then it will display result as null
```